# Manipulating of a larger matrix to increase search time of a smaller matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vectorization

So given a larger image and a smaller image that is located within the larger image.  What can be done to the larger image in a separate function to help decrease search time.  The small image is a pixel to pixel similar to the large.  Trying to find the small one's exact location.

Given:

```
function [x] = generate_value(big_image)

function [row, col] = searchImages(big_image, small_image, x)
```

where x is generated in the other function. To be more specific the x vale can by anything. A structure, hash mapping, anything isnt not super reliant on built in matlab functions.

Unfortunately, I do need to use the two function signatures given.

Any ideas of what i could to the larger image to speed up the search.  Time is important.

Comment: I'm sure you mean help *decrease* search time:) Your question might be quite broad, but I'm unfamiliar with this subject. Maybe you should tag with [image-processing] (if it applies).

Comment: yeah decrease definitely. Yeah Ill add that, but i dont think image processing is too relevant.  More so need to focus on matrix manipulation and vectorization.

Comment: Well, your question didn't specify whether the match was *exact*. I thought you need to find something *almost the same* in the big picture as the small one. And anyway: without any information about *how* the small image might be located in the big one, I'm not sure there's much anyone can say (by which I mean your question might be too broad). For instance, how does `x` come into play in the search? Anyway, I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: yep that is my problem to is that x generation can be literally anything that can be plugged in to the second function to help decrease search time.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help beyond telling you that opencv and others have a feature called [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) (link to python-related stuff, but matlab [works with opencv](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html))

Comment: yeah limited to what i can use that is built in to be honest. thanks anyways :)

Comment: Apologies, but I don't really know what 'x' does in searchImages. Have you looked at https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html ? It does exactly what you want it to do, in that it returns a matrix with a peak at which the small_image template has been matched in the large_image.

Comment: yeah so basically 'x' is some calculation, manipulation, search anything that i would like to do on the larger image that once plugged into the second function signature to help speed up the search for smaller once everything is entered into the second function.  Everyone seems to point me to normxcorr2 but I am limited in what I can use.